# Unable to change path after executing mvnw package in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory

I'm trying to create `.jar` out of spring application using `mvnw package` command and execute it by moving into `current-path/target` folder. But the command `cd "target"` doesn't execute in batch file

my batch file:

```
mvnw package

cd "target"

start javaw -jar kissangrahak-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: What is mvnw? Is it an .exe?

Comment: `@Call "P:\ath\To\mvnw.cmd" package`, followed by `@Start "" /D "S:\ome\location\target" "T:\he\DirectoryOf\javaw.exe" -jar "kissangrahak-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"`, should be the general template to follow; _(where it expects `kissangrahak-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` to be in the new working directory, `S:\ome\location\target`)_.The important part being `Call` on your first line, because you want the control to return to the script after the `mvnw` batch file has completed.

Comment: I've fixed the tags you added. In future, please don't apply some random tags as you did here, read the related tag info before...

Comment: Use `start C:\full\file\path\of\javaw.exe`

Comment: Do you mean like in my already existing comment @NekoMusume?

Comment: @Compo Yes indeed